# Run a server from a flask route

Tags: python, flask, subprocess

I have a flask server (app1) in file1:

```
from flask import Flask
app1 = Flask(__name__)

@app1.route('/', methods=['POST']):
    return "Hello!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app1.run(port=8080, debug=True)
```

And another flask server (app2) in file2:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request
import subprocess
from time import sleep

app2 = Flask(__name__)

@app2.route('/run-path', methods=['POST'])
def run_path():
    command_str = request.json.get('command')
    command = command_str.split()
    path_to_add = command[1]
    os.environ['PYTHONPATH'] += f":{path_to_add}" # Adding the file that's going to be ran 
    # to PYTHONPATH to prevent import errors 
    
    subprocess.run(
        command,
        env=os.enivron.copy(),
        stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    )
    sleep(600)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app2.run(port=2222, debug=True)
```

When someone sends a request to app2 (port 2222), it should run a python command, which is sometimes a flask server. The problem is that anything goes wrong when trying to run this command using subprocess.run.

**It seems like it works, but when I'm trying to send a request to app1 (The server which we tried to start with subprocess), there's no response.**
The server is essentially down and it seems like the command did nothing.

If I set stdout to `subprocess.STDOUT`, I get this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1758, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1752, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1147, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/Users/galshahar/Desktop/Projects/PychramProjects/cba/src/api.py", line 48, in <module>
    app.run(port=8080, debug=True)
  File "/Users/galshahar/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 943, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "/Users/galshahar/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 814, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "/Users/galshahar/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 774, in inner
    fd=fd)
  File "/Users/galshahar/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 660, in make_server
    passthrough_errors, ssl_context, fd=fd)
  File "/Users/galshahar/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 574, in __init__
    socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  File "/Users/galshahar/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/socket.py", line 463, in fromfd
    nfd = dup(fd)
OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

Is what I'm trying to do is possible? What am I missing? I'm kinda lost :(

Thanks.

Comment: This looks super insecure...

Comment: Yeah I know it is but there's a common sense behind it, it runs inside a container, inside a closed network and being ran by company's employees only.

Comment: But this is literally taking an arbitrary string over HTTP and passing it to `subprocess.run()`, if i tried doing this under any circumstance on my employers network I'm pretty sure black helicopters would instantly descend and guys wearing balaclavas would rappel from the ceiling and tackle me. There are other, more secure ways of doing this. How about using SSH with pre-generated keys?

Comment: Hahahaha you made me laugh here, please elaborate on the SSH method, how would you do it? I'm trying to figure out if this method works for my needs... @Z4-tier

Comment: you can generate SSH key pairs using `ssh-keygen`, and configure your Dockerfile and/or entrypoint script to install the public part key inside the container. Then someone from outside the container would be able to use the private key to authenticate without needing a password. The only challenge might be that most base docker images don't have SSHD installed out of the box, so you would need to get that running inside the container (either from the Dockerfile, in the entrypoint script, or by building your own custom image (or finding an image that has it, but I don't know of any)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I can tell you how to work around it.  If you look at the traceback, `flask` calls a package called `werkzeug` to do the work.  `werkzeug` puts a note in the environment when it has to create a socket, presumably so it can just reuse that socket in forks.  In your case, the second process inherits that environment, so it thinks an `fd` already exists and tries to reuse it, but the `fd` does not exist in this process.

The ugly solution that should work is to add this in your second script before starting port 8080 (or 2226, based on the original traceback ;):

```
    del os.environ["WERKZEUG_SERVER_FD"]
```

Comment: They consider what you're doing to be heresy, and don't consider this a bug.  I guess you proceed at your own risk.

Comment: You might want to read their reply.  I'm not good enough with flask to know if this works for you.  https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/2067